# Skip foreach X positions

Tags: c#

I want skip my in foreach. For example:

```
foreach(Times t in timeList)
{ 
      if(t.Time == 20)
      {    
          timeList.Skip(3);   
      }                           
}
```

I want "jump" 3 positions in my list.. If, in my if block **t.Id = 10** after skip I want get **t.Id = 13**

Comment: Then just use a normal for...loop with an indexer and increment the indexer when you need

Comment: @Steve can you give one example please?

Comment: also why you are talking about an ID property when in code you test for the property Time == 20?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? If you use a `for` loop then you can just step the index forward as needed:

```
for (var x = 0; x < timeList.Length; x++)
{
    if (timeList[x].Time == 20)
    {
        // option 1
        x += 2; // 'x++' in the for loop will +1, 
                // we are adding +2 more to make it 3? 

        // option 2
        // x += 3; // just add 3!
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add 2, you only skip two. You still operate on the current index.

Comment: @dekuShrub if you are on 20, the next index would be 21.... if you wanted to +3 from 20 and land on 23 then +2 would bring you instantly to 22 and the next loop `x` would be 23.  it ultimately boils down to whether we want to jump from 20 to 23 ... or 20 to 24... again if we `x+=3` in that loop -- the next value for `x` would be *24* --- Am I correct?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right!

Comment: The thing is though, that you're not actually skipping the current value, you're only incrementing the index, not skipping the current. A bit confusing, but I think it's like that?

Comment: @dekuShrub it's a semantic difference. we're at a disagreement about what Marco intended to accomplish by adding 3.  Are we skipping ahead to 23 (20+3) or skipping 3 iterations (21, 22, 23) thus landing on 24?  it's subjective.

Comment: Yes, partly. But you run the loop body for 20 and then skip 21, 22 to continue running the loop for 23. So you're not actually skipping 3 elements, you're skipping 2. I am convinced that when Marco wrote `Skip(3)` he shouldn't whant to run the code for those 3 elements, but that could be wrong as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify an enumerable in-flight, as it were, like you could the index of a `for` loop; you **must** account for it up front. Fortunately there are several way to do this.

Here's one:

```
foreach(Times t in timeList.Where(t => t.Time < 20 || t.Time > 22))
{ 
 
}
```

There's also the `.Skip()` option, but to use it you must break the list into two separate enumerables and then rejoin them:

```
var times1 = timeList.TakeWhile(t => t.Time != 20);
var times2 = timeList.SkipeWhile(t => t.Time != 20).Skip(3);
foreach(var t in times1.Concat(times2))
{

}
```

But that's not exactly efficient, as it requires iterating over the first part of the sequence twice (and won't work at all for Read Once -style sequences). To fix this, you can make a custom enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> SkipTrigger, int SkipCount)
{
    bool triggered = false;
    int SkipsRemaining = 0;

    var e = items.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!triggered && SkipTrigger(e.Current))
        {
            triggered = true;
            SkipsRemaining = SkipCount;
        }

        if (triggered)
        {
             SkipsRemaining--;
             if (SkipsRemaining == 0) triggered = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
             yield return e.Current; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TDskN):

```
foreach(Times t in timeList.SkipAt(t => t.Times == 20, 3))
{ 
                           
}
```

But again: you still need to decide about this up front, rather than inside the loop body.

For fun, I felt like adding an overload that uses another predicate to tell the enumerator when to resume:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> SkipTrigger, Predicate<T> ResumeTrigger)
{
    bool triggered = false;

    var e = items.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!triggered && SkipTrigger(e.Current))
        {
            triggered = true;
        }

        if (triggered)
        {
             if (ResumeTrigger(e.Current)) triggered = false;               
        } 
        else 
        {
             yield return e.Current; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` with some simple variables.

```cs
int skipCount = 0;
bool skip = false;

foreach (var x in myList)
{
    if (skipCount == 3)
    {
        skip = false;
        skipCount = 0;
    }
    
    if (x.time == 20)
    {
        skip = true;
        skipCount = 0;
    }

    if (skip)
    {
        skipCount++;
        continue;
    }
    
    // here you do whatever you don't want to skip
}
```

Or if you can use a for-loop, increase the index like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < times.Count)
{
    if (times[i].time == 20)
    {
        i += 2; // 2 + 1 loop increment
        continue; 
    }

    // here you do whatever you don't want to skip
}
```